# AC circuit analyse

Tags: ac, circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

I have to find all currents in the circuit.
What I got so far is:
$$Z_1 = wl_2 j - \frac{j}{wC_2} = j \Omega$$
$$Z_2 = wl_1 j = j \Omega$$
$$Z_3 = R + wl_3 j - \frac{j}{wC_3} = 2 \Omega$$
$$i_{g_1} = -2A$$
$$e_4 = j-1V$$
$$i_{g_5} = -jA$$

How do you use KVL in this situation?
Can you use KVL when you have ideal current sources?
I tried node method but I am getting wrong answers.

Can someone solve this for me(or give me some hints) cos I am stuck.

[image]

Comment: Just a general recommendation, always redraw your circuit in to an easier to see form. This will one help you visualize your loops and nodes better and will give you an insight as to how the circuit is structured and this insight will also help you determine an approach for analysis

Answer (score 1):

I'll give hints since it kinda seems like a school problem.

You can most certainly use KVL for this problem. Find the loops as usual, that will give you 3 independent equations.

You will also need to use KCL for this problem. Pick independent junctions and write out the currents flowing in/out of it. You can plug in the current sources here.

The combination of the KVL loops and KCL junctions will give you all the independent equations you need. Then it's just a matter of substitution and algebraic manipulation.